# Generic Interface with property

Tags: c#

i have one interface

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for IBindable
/// </summary>
public interface IBindable<T>
{
    // Property declaration:
    T Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement this interface in my class

```
public class MyTextBox :IBindable<string>
{
    //now i how can i implement Text peroperty here 
}
```

I don't want to implement it like

```
string IBindable<string>.Text
{  
    get { return "abc";} 
    set { //assigne value } 
}
```

I want to implement it like

```
public string Text
{
    get{} set {}
}
```

Comment: I can't grasp the problem... you can do what you said...

Comment: I'm guessing the OP didn't realize this was valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are free to do this.  This is an implicit interface implementation.

The following is valid C#:

```
public interface IBindable<T>
{
    // Property declaration:
    T Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MyTextBox : IBindable<string>
{

    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When you implement an interface, you are free to implement it implicitly, as above, or explicitly, which would be your second option:

```
string IBindable<string>.Text
{  get { return "abc";} set { // assign value } }
```

The difference is in usage.  When you use the first option, the `Text` property becomes a publicly visible property on the type itself (`MyTextBox`).  This allows:

```
MyTextBox box = new MyTextBox();
box.Text = "foo";
```

However, if you implement it explicitly, you need to be using your interface directly:

```
MyTextBox box = new MyTextBox();
IBindable<string> bindable = box;
box.Text = "foo"; // This will work in both cases
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyTextBox : IBindable<string>
{
    //now i how can i implement Text peroperty here 
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```